# PHP - MySQL 1.000.000 records query optimization

Tags: php, mysql

thanks for the time spent on my question and sorry if it has been already asked something similar.

I have the following schematic of a DB:

[image: db scheme]

I have only SELECT permissions for the DB.
And my query tend to run from 2-3 secs to 10 secs with the current setup.
I am asked to optimize to the best of the current structure provisioned and my SQL looks like this: (I need to get the total income for each product within all the orders which are 1 month interval)

```
SELECT items.`type` AS type, 
  DATE(orders.date) AS date,
   sum(items.price * orders.quantity * clients.discount_percent/100) AS total
  FROM orders
 INNER JOIN items ON orders.item = items.id
 INNER JOIN clients ON orders.`client` = clients.id
 GROUP BY DATE(orders.date), items.`type`
```

I was thinking about chunking the results by modifying the SQL working with the data on the PHP side - but not sure if it will be effective though.

Would love to hear form ya if this can be optimized :).

KR,
Dippy

P.S.
EXPLAIN results:
[EXPLAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgUWS.png)

Comment: Do you have index on date column (also item, client)?

Comment: What indexes do you have on these tables? What does an EXPLAIN show for this query?

Comment: You should start by obtaining the explain plan. But if you aren't allowed to create indexes, it's going to be fun.

Comment: There is nothing extraneous in your query, it is correct to fetch the data you want.  Performance here will likely be related to indexing on the involved tables, run EXPLAIN to look for bottlenecks.

Comment: if you dont have index on your conditional columns, and you aren't allowed to change the db structuring, you can make runtime indexes, query and indexes are released. it is a little expensive solution but will do the trick of shortning the query time along with not altering DB structure.

Comment: `orders.date` is a date or datetime? The `date()` there can be removed if it already is a date.

Comment: What do you mean by "within all the orders which are 1 month interval"? That month, whatever you mean with it, is not reflected in your query at all. If you only need e.g. data for the last month, you should add that filter to your query, it will greatly reduce the execution time (if you do it correctly).

Comment: @chris85 - It is a datetime argument, though it is formatted as follow YYYY-MM-DD-HH:MM:SS and I need only a daily plan, so I use the DATE function in order to get the format: YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @Solarflare - All the 1.000.000 records are related to a single month (2015-01-01 : 2015-01-31)

Comment: @Gunnrryy - Can you advice on where should I look for creating those indexes, not familar with them, thanks in advance :)

Comment: 3 Primary Keys - on each table `ID`
1 Index in `orders.date`

Comment: Using the `date()` removes the index there. If you can make it a `date` column, or create a second column with just `date` it would run better I think.

Comment: @chris85 - True but I believe the issue is in the query itself - the query needs to pass trough all the data in order to make the calculations `sum(items.price * orders.quantity * clients.discount_percent/100) AS total` each quantity is a record in the orders table, is not specific it is similar to SELECT * FROM orders, if I am not wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking , your performance problem is due by a full table scan over "orders"

It’s strange a so big run time for a small dataset (~10MB). A similar query on my server takes more or less 1  sec.

Try to optimize the data type to fit in the smaller data size. 
(For index you must use int).

Check if Orders.Data has a index.

Check if Orders.Data is type Date to improve index performance.

In all case, you are using some aggregate functions (group and sum) , these type of function are very expensive because the server first generative a big table with all the data and after perform the aggregate functions.

If your performance issue is due to the server configuration (workload, ram or …) you can cache the result to avoid to recalculate every time all the results.

Answer (score 1):

The fields `orders.item` and `orders.client` are indexed? If you create a table with Phpmyadmin you have to specify the fields as index and the relations that gonna have, so when you're make a query like that using a `JOIN` the query is most optimized for searchs.

Of course you can  `ALTER` your table and set that fields like `INDEX` but they have to be of the same type or the relationship will can't especified! Example your `PRIMARY KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY` must be `INT UNSIGNED`.

I hope you consider this answer useful.